# Stacked row chart

Tags: excel

Hi I've been struggling with this for few hours now.

In column A I have a list of projects, in columns B:D milestones at which they're currently at labeled with 0's & 1's

I want to show on a stacked row chart that Project 1 is at Milestone 1 which corresponds to 1 in the column of Milestone 1, and similarly for Project 2 & 3

The results I'm looking for is as in the picture

Is there some solution to it?

Thanks a lot for your help

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/27yDg.png)

Answer (score 0):

TLDR :

1. Put T/F formula..
2. select region > Colour the text = background
3. select region > Conditional formatting.. , if TRUE, green the text & background.

Full :

1. Insert these formula and drag till column D.

`B9  ->  =IF(OR(B2=1,C9=TRUE),TRUE,FALSE)
B11  ->  =IF(OR(B3=1,C11=TRUE),TRUE,FALSE)
B13  ->  =IF(OR(B4=1,C13=TRUE),TRUE,FALSE)`

2. select the chart region, Colour the text & background as white.
3. select the chart region, Home > Conditional formatting > highlight cell = TRUE, [Custom format : green the text & background ].

Done.

Please share if it works.. ( :